# Android - What folder can I use to save the apps data against wipe?

Tags: android, android-rom

I am building the Android 9 Pie GSI from the AOSP and flashing it into the PIXEL 3XL. I have my own application and I have added it to the Android 9 Pie GSI ROM - so this application builds together with the ROM. This application has privileged app permissions (located in `/system/priv-app`) and its data must be protected from the userdata wiping.

I tried to use the `/persist` for this purpose, but it's read only. I tried the `/mnt/vendor/persist/` and  I got the "permission denied" error.

What folder can I use to save the apps data?

Comment: If your app is a system app, then you can use root permissions for it. You can mount the directory as writable if it is read-only

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, it's a nice advice, but I cannot change the app's source code. Instead I can change the AOSP-settings. Maybe You know how to mount the directory as writable?

Comment: I don;t know unfortunately. I only know that it is possible

Answer (score 0):

The answer here at: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/47951/56147 will help. Please take a look at it. In summary the link says that:

> "All apps (root or not) have a default data directory, which is `/data/data/<package_name>`. By default, the apps databases, settings, and all other data go here. If an app expects huge amounts of data to be stored, or for other reasons wants to "be nice to internal storage", there's a corresponding directory on the SDCard (`Android/data/<package_name>`)."

which I believe is mostly correct and should help set you on the right path. As you have root access, you can write anywhere, including where the user has no access.

Comment: sure, and it still has nothing to do with `data must be protected from the userdata wiping`

Comment: I have tried the `/data/data/myappname/` - folder, but it does not suit  - @Vladyslav Matviienko has already mentioned the fact about the data protection

Comment: The variant with the SD-card also does not suit((